# Word for prematurely calling a middle-aged person old?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, pejorative-language

My title may not completely reflect the meaning I am trying to get across.

I am writing a card for my dad (who is 58 this year) to go alongside a gift I am getting him. I know he enjoys shooting, but he is finding is harder due to a lasting injury to his left arm he sustained some time ago, so am getting him a shooting stick (specifics not really relevant).

Basically, he could take it that I am *patronizing* (this is the word I am unhappy about) him, and I would like to make a jokey reference to this in the card. So far I've written;

> Have a great day - I hope the present is suitable (and not too ...)

I would like to write something along the lines of patronizing or belittling, but these do not feel right to me, but I cannot think of the word I would actually like to use.

Thanks

Comment: Is your dad into puns? How about *paternizing*?

Comment: - I've read that these can be good for dealing with shooting pains -

Comment: "I hope the present is suitable (and not too liable to over-analysis)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps one of the [following](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/condescending)

> condescending
>
> debasing
>
> degrading
>
> demeaning
>
> dishonoring
>
> humbling
>
> humiliating
>
> shameful
>
> focused on your advancing decrepitude

Comment: Ha - I'm sure the last one would go down a treat ;) Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I'm not too fond of several of these alternatives, in that they seem less suitable than the O.P.'s original suggestions. The context here is a good-natured jest; if it were my birthday card, I'd wouldn't think much about _patronizing_ or _belittling_, but _humiliating_? "I hope this present is not too _shameful_?" _Degrading_ or _debasing_? I'd advise the O.P. to stick with _belittling_ or _patronizing_ before choosing from among these.

Comment: @J.R. The level of denegration acceptable in familial repartee is idiosyncratic to the relationship. I do not presume to know the scope of their respective japes. And I find your scathing criticism patronizing, belittling and humiliating and I am therefore leaving this site forever! You won't have bib to kick around any longer!!! (See, the level of offense **is** in the eye of the beholder.) But I (and Luke, I suspect) get your point.

Comment: I feel compelled to upvote this now, just because of your brilliant comment. BTW, not to sound patronizing, but I did think _condescending_ was a decent choice (which is why it was conspicuously absent from my "belittling" criticism). :^)

Comment: @J.R. Well, maybe I'll come back. Actually, all but the last of the list came from various thesaurus references for *condescending*, which *was* the first term that came to my mind. (With my family, I'd be harsher.)

Comment: I think *demeaning* may be the most appropriate for me (and my father). I'm posting the card this morning, so will accept demeaning as the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Possible additions to the list by @bib

- mortifying
- undignified
- tactless
- inelegant
- tasteless

Comment: I like #3 & #5 (not too keen on the others, though).